# Saving data from datagridview to a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm very new to C# and visual studio (I have only used python up until this point)
The issue that I have is I want to quickly populate a datatable in my dataset with test data. The method so far was to create a data grid view of said table (PATIENT) fill in the info and either exit the program or press a button to save. exiting the program doesn't save for me and I am not sure what code will allow me to save from a data grid view.
[image: table hierarchy for all the data entered]

[image: Please ignore the boxes behind this was just trying to get data to save]

TL:DR Anyone know of the correct code to save a datagridview to a dataset.
Its completely possible I'm not even using a dataset correctly -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DataSet is 'an in-memory cache of data retrieved from a data source' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-6.0). In your case, it sounds like you haven't bound to an external 'data source'; the grid is empty and the user types in the information. You will need to persist that data out to some sort of storage, most likely a database, if you want it to persist between sessions.

Comment: so in simpleton terms its just ram but for a database? This is what happens when my comp sci teacher expects too much

Comment: yeah - I think that's probably a good way to think about it. If you want to have an entry show up after shutting down and starting up your app, you *must* save it somewhere: in a text file on disk (yuck), in a database (good), etc.

Comment: alrighty thanks man, ill go bash my head against a keyboard and build a database hopefully